# Running application in compaitibility mode in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Till `IE9`, my application was working fine with compatibility mode on. Now our uses are being upgraded to IE11 but it seems IE11 doesn't have option to view the page in compatibility mode. Compatibility view setting in IE11 is adding the whole intranet domain which I don't want as few local websites are expecting this setting to off.

```
http:\\intranet.xxxx.com\XXXX\YYYY - Application 1
http:\\intranet.xxxx.com\AAAA\BBBB - Application 2
```

With IE11, my UI is not rendering properly due to css issues. I tried below tag but it also not working. Is there any way either code, web server config or simple client side setting to run the individual website in compaitibility mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: *Starting with IE11, document modes are considered deprecated and should no longer be used. Webpages that require legacy document modes to display properly should be rewritten to use features defined by modern standards* from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx). You better face facts and fix your css...

Answer (score 0):

If they worked in IE9's compatibility mode, have you tried this?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```